# is it possible to work with the ROS environment on a esp32?

Tags: ros, robotics, esp32

I would like to be able to work with the Robotic OS `ROS. org` environment on an ESP32.

Searches carried out directly on the `ROS. org` website do not give any indication.

Comment: Without some more information nobody is able to answer this question. Please add some information how you want to use the ESP32 like ROS master / slave, serial / bluetooth / i2c interface, ...

Answer (score 0):

I Don't Think ESP32 Has Enough Proc-Power For A Linux-based OS and ROS Master To Work

However, There's Another Project ROS2 That's Exactly For This Kind Of Devices But There's No Stable Version But Betas

Here's The [Link](https://github.com/ros2)